# Правильная перезапись данных в redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, create-react-app, redux-middleware

Мне приходит массив объектов через сокеты, я записываю эти данные в store редакса.

Но! когда мы что-то изменяем на сайте ( в моем случае это создание нового лобби либо изменение каких-либо данных в нем ) то нам приходит только небольшая часть данных ( пример: `UPDATE_LOBBY: { user: admin, ..., ... }`

И вот вопрос: как перезаписывать эти данные в redux правильно? ведь reducer должен быть чистой функцией, в action тоже бредово выглядит, тогда где? или как?

Comment: добавьте к вопросу код пожалуйста)

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин Добавить не проблема, только что именно? сокеты? код который приходит в сокеты? redux? reducer?

Comment: код редьюсера, мне кажется что проблема там

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин так а проблемы нету, есть вопрос - как это правильно делать. Сейчас я в reducer'е просто записываю через через return { ...state, fields: action.payload }

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин а каким образом именно перезаписывать части этих самых fields - не понимаю, т.к все известные мне варианты не адекватны в рамках redux ( я делал всю перезапись в reducer'е )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все данные в Redux Store передаются только через Action. Новое состояние Store генерируется на основе предыдущего его состояния и действия (Action).

Частичное обновление подразумевает копирование из предыдущего состояния ссылок на объекты которые не поменялись, любые изменения должны порождать новые объекты. Пример частичного обновления Store:

```js
function reduce(state, action) { 
    switch (action.type) {
        case "CHANGE_DATA_ENTRY": {
            const previosDataEntry = state.data[action.key]

            const changeUser = action.user ? {user: action.user} : {}
            const changeEmail = action.email ? {email: action.email} : {}
            const changeAvatarURI = action.avatarURI ? {avatar_uri: action.avatarURI} : {}

            return {
                ...state,
                data: {
                    ...state.data,
                    [action.key]: {
                        ...previosDataEntry,
                        ...changeUser,
                        ...changeEmail,
                        ...changeAvatarURI
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return state
}
```